# Would this question on future-proof programming fit on Programmers SE?

Tags: support, migration, on-topic-definition

Last week I asked [a question on future-proof programming](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14756472/974555) on Stack Overflow. It was closed as off-topic there. I flagged it for migration, but although the flag was deemed helpful, the non-migration [appears to imply rejection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167700/172266).

Is my question, closed on Stack Overflow, a good fit on Programmers? Was a migration rejected? Why (not)?

Comment: Looks like your question has been migrated to P.SE now.

Comment: @GlenH7 Yes, indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your question would be on-topic for P.SE.

1. It's asking about the broader aspects of design
2. You've clearly done some homework in identifying where problems have come up

You could make your question stronger by indicating some of the things you've attempted but are either unsure of or haven't worked well for you.

I have flagged the question requesting a migration to P.SE, but I'm a nobody, so feel free to flag again and point them to this meta discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the migration issue. Migration from Stack Overflow to Programmers has to be by moderator action.

If the moderator who saw your flag had *any* doubt over whether the question would be a good fit for Programmers they were right to not migrate it. Your flag would still be marked as helpful as the question isn't suitable for Stack Overflow.

The simplest thing to do is repost your question - but please, please make sure you are asking a constructive question.

Comment: I thought reposting was against Stack Exchange rules?

Comment: Not if it's been closed on Stack Overflow, though I would consider revising the post before you do.